# Cannot get Python to run from SPSS syntax

Tags: python, spss

I installed Python 2.7.2 and the Python SPSS plugin, but when I try to run a very simple syntax with Python BEGIN / END from within SPSS all i get in the output window is a log-line with the code

I'm trying to run the following

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
print "Hello world"
END PROGRAM.
```

And this is what the output window says:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
print "Hello world"
END PROGRAM.
```

I'd expect the output window to say:

```
Hello world
```

I don't see any errors or anything.

Answer (score 3):

I had lots of problems with the R extension for SPSS and they have still not been fully resolved.
 
Anyways,this statement should allow you to see the results of your code, as it supposedly shows 'generated syntax':

```
SET PRINTBACK ON MPRINT ON
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
print "Hello World"
END PROGRAM.
```

In theory that should print 'Hello World' in the output viewer

I checked it in the [manual](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/20.0/en/pythonplugin/Manuals/Python_Integration_Package_for_IBM_SPSS_Statistics.pdf) and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the manual. In case anyone wants to view it in the browser, see here: [Python Integration Package for IBM SPSS Statistics](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_22.0.0/kc_gen/com.ibm.spss.statistics.python.help_statistics_python_plugin_uber_project-gen1.html).